# Speeding up depth image to point-cloud conversion (Python)

Tags: python, performance, computer-vision, cython, point-clouds

I am currently trying to speed up the conversion from depth to point cloud in python. At the moment the code looks like this:

```
   color_points = []
   for v in range(depth.shape[1]):
        for u in range(depth.shape[0]):
            z = depth[u,v] / self.scaling_factor
            if z == 0:   # here np.where can be used prior to the loop
                continue
            x = (u - self.center_x) * z / self.focalLength     # u and v are needed, no clue how to do this
            y = (v - self.center_y) * z / self.focalLength

            color_points.append([x, y, z])
```

My main issue is, that I don't know any function (like np.where) that would speed up the looping through the image array, while still having the indices of the pixel (e.g. u and v). The indices are needed, as the calculation depends on the location of the pixel on the sensor.

Cython would be an option to speed it up, but I still think there must be a better function available within NumPy.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Added Z calculation to the function. The scaling factor depends on the format you get the depth image in. In my case, I get the depth in [mm] and convert it to meters.

Comment: Please provide the code to compute `z`

Comment: @francoisr Just added the Z calculation, as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my stab at it, using `np.mgrid` to compute `u` and `v` in a numpy array which avoids the slow looping and allows to take advantage of numpy's universal functions.

```
import numpy as np
depth = np.random.uniform(size=(4,4)) # Just so this sample can be run
grid = np.mgrid[0:depth.shape[0],0:depth.shape[1]]
u, v = grid[0], grid[1]
z = depth / scaling_factor
adjusted_z = z / focal_length
x = (u - center_x) * adjusted_z
y = (v - center_y) * adjusted_z
color_points = np.stack([x,y,z], axis=-1).reshape(-1,3)
```

Note that I haven't filtered the `color_points` for `z=0`, but you can do it using `color_points[z.reshape(-1) != 0]`.  Also be mindful that my `color_points` will be ordered differently from yours (`u` before `v`). It probably doesn't matter in depth estimation scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I never even thought about filling an array with u and v and then using this for further calculations. Definitely an easy work around!
Regarding the ordering: For point clouds it doesn't matter at all which points come first.